# Average of last n matches using awk

Tags: linux, awk

I have a growing file. while will write the log of my application process. In that file, there is a log for "speed" as below

```
(some text)
speed= 1x
(some text)
speed= 1x
(some text)
speed= 1x
(some text)
speed= 0.9x
..
..
(some text)
speed= 0.8x
(some text)
```

I have tried the below code to get the average value of speed.

```
 awk '/speed/ {gsub("x","");print $2}' $PROCESS_LOG_FILE | awk -F : '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/NR}'
```

is it possible to get the average of the last 120 entries? I have tried with grep and tail, but it took a long time since its a growing file.

Comment: Now, "last 120" with a "growing file" might be a bit difficult to catch... you may need to define a point in time that you start the data collection.

Comment: @RudiC Yes....finally, I end up with `tail -n120 ` between 2 `awk`s

Comment: I tought you were going for a `tail -f some.log | awk '...'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit far fetched, maybe, but as `tac` will `lseek` the momentary file end, you'd define the necessary point in time, and from there go backwards until 120 speeds encountered:

```
tac file | awk '/speed/ {SUM += $2; if (++C == 120) {print SUM/C; exit}}'
```

Or to handle inputs that might have fewer than 120 occurrences of the pattern:

```
tac file | awk '/speed/ {SUM += $2; if (++C == 120) exit}
                END {if (C) print SUM/C}'
```

Comment: @ Stéphane Chazelas: I was transiently thinking of that as well but didn't get at your reasoning. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use perl rather than awk for this: quite straightforward to remember just the last 120 speeds:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -nE '
    if (/speed= ([\d.]+)/) {@speeds = ($1, @speeds)[0..119]} 
    # could also write:
    #   if (/speed= ([\d.]+)/) {push @speeds, $1; shift @speeds if @speeds > 120}

    END {say @speeds == 0 ? "No matches" : sum(@speeds)/@speeds}
' speed.log
```

Comment: got an error as `Illegal division by zero at -e line 1, <> line 5700.
END failed--call queue aborted, <> line 5700.`

Comment: Hmm, sounds like that regex has found no matches.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`grep speed test | tail -n 120 | cut -d " " -f 2 | cut -d "x" -f 1 | awk -F : '{sum+=$1} END {print sum/NR}'`

I just put your input into a file called `test` and ran that. Output:

`0.94`

Can't tell what performance will be on a huge file, though.

Comment: your first 3 pips will do similar as `awk '/speed/ {gsub("x","");print $2}'`

Comment: i would like to know is there any way to get the last n matches using `awk`

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to add that. Just pipe the output of grep into `tail -n 120`

Comment: it throws me an error `Binary file progress.log matches`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use a circular table, here is a sample code with last 5 values

```
BEGIN { maxi=5 ; c=0 ; nb=0 ;  }
/^speed/ { list[nb++]=$2 ; nb=nb % maxi ;
   c++ ; if (c> maxi) c=maxi ;
   s=0 ;
   for(i=0;i<=c;i++) s+=list[i] ;
   printf "NR: %d, c=%d, s=%d AVG : %3.2f\n",NR,c,s,s/c ;
}
```

you can test on a sample file (or on command line, values to be entered on command line).

```
awk -f avg.awk sample.txt
```

then replace 5 by 120, and `printf` line by what suit you.

note that `+=$2` will ignore trailling `x`.